# Clarification on fsetpos, C++

Tags: c++, cstdio

I am a little confused with function ***fsetpos*** in the stdio.h library. I want to be to write to different indexes (i.e do not want to write to a file contiguously) in a file. I was considering using fsetpos however the documentation states..

```
The internal file position indicator associated with stream is set to the position 
represented by pos, which is a pointer to an fpos_t object whose value shall have been
previously obtained by a call to fgetpos.
```

It does not make sense to me that I have to set the position based on the call from fgetpos. Whats the point since it will just set it to the position it is already set at. Or I am I not understanding it correctly ?

Comment: more detail, add code please...

Comment: If you found the answer, write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C11 standard, `fseek` has a similar limitation:

> For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be `SEEK_SET`

The reason is that text streams don't have a one-to-one mapping between the actual bytes of the source and the bytes you would get from `fgetc`; e.g. on windows systems, the newline character in C tends to be translated into a sequence of two binary characters: carriage return, then line feed.

Consequently, the notion of arbitrarily positioning a text stream based on a numerical index is fraught with complications and surprises.

In fact, the documentation of `ftell` warns

> For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.

Binary streams don't have this limitation, although

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a whence value of `SEEK_END`

---

The above assumes you are working with byte-oriented streams. Wide-oriented streams have additional restrictions. e.g. under `Streams`:

> Binary wide-oriented streams have the file-positioning restrictions ascribed to both text and binary streams

and

> For wide-oriented streams, after a successful call to a file-positioning function that leaves the file position indicator prior to the end-of-file, a wide character output function can overwrite a partial multibyte character; any file contents beyond the byte(s) written are henceforth indeterminate

`fsetpos` does more than just set the file position: again from the C11 standard:

> The `fsetpos` function sets the `mbstate_t` object (if any) and file position indicator

which makes it more suitable for setting the position in a wide-oriented streams.